# Swift - How to return Media(Image,audio,video) from url written in function of a class

Tags: swift3

I am trying to access a url which can return either audio/image/video. I have created a helper class as below :

```
class LoadAsyncMedia{


   static func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _  response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in
            completion(data, response, error)
            }.resume()
    }


    static func  downloadMedia(url: URL)  {
        print("Download Started \(url)")
        getDataFromUrl(url: url) { (data, response, error)  in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
            print("Download Finished")
            print( response!)
            print( data)
                }
    }
}
```

Below is call i m using to fetch the image first but i dont know how to convert the response into string then convert it into respective media.

```
LoadAsyncMedia.downloadMedia(url: URL(string: "http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg")!)
```

Comment: actually, your data is the response so to convert it into a string or store it into a custom model, you have to create a model and then store your data into that model

Comment: i need to know how to convert all response into string i need that bit of code

Comment: show me your json respone,accordingly you will be able to make the model clas

Comment: its not json response its media for eg image url http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg

Comment: so the response is media url and you want to convert it into string .correct ?

Comment: yes for all media i get image url/ video url / audio url

Comment: to convert a media url into string do this :
var directoryURL: NSURL
var urlString: String = directoryURL.absoluteString
// OR
var urlString: String = directoryURL.relativeString
// OR
var urlString: String = directoryURL.relativePath
// OR
var urlString: String = directoryURL.path
// etc.